# how to set up ssh key in windows 7 machine

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys, git-bash

I am learning git.

My friend set up a git repo in his server and he give me the link for clone it. He also provide me a .ssh folder. and i see there is two file id_rsa.pub and id_rsa.

I already install git so I goto to my user folder and see there is also one .ssh folder with that two file. Now I just copy and paste my friends key pair but when I trying to clone it it ask me the password.
What wrong I made ? 
what is the right process ?

Answer (score 4):

The right process would be for you to:

- not override your public and private key with the ones from your friend
- not keep the public private key from your friend
- give your own public key `%HOME%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub` to your friend for him/her to copy yhat public key in the server `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

And make sure you start a git session using [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat), in order for the environment variable `HOME` to be properly set (usually to `%USERPROFILE%`)

Comment: hi @VonC thanks. He supply me the whole .ssh folder and told me clone and the. Then I can modify it and push it. But when I want to do it it shows me some warning `code'Cloning into 'test-com'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.`code`

Comment: @TrissaPanda the warning is expected if that git repo was empty on the server side. The clone has worked. But it is best to *not* reuse/share ssh private keys.